# Spring Config Server delivering config file but not activating profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a config server.
I'm migrating from 2.2 to 2.6 and I've seen that properties file are changed.

I have a situation that I don't think is covered (or maybe I misunderstood).

My situation is that I've a Config server that deliver:

```
application.properties --> containing properties shared by every microservices
application-dev.properties --> containing properties specific for dev profile
application-test.properties --> containing properties specific for test profile
application-production.properties --> containing properties specific for production profile
microservicesName.properties --> containing specific properties
microservicesName-mysql.properties --> if I use mysql profile
microservicesName-h2.properties --> if I use h2 profile
```

Before 2.4 I used to put in microservices application.properties path to fetch configuration from config server and in application.properties delivered by config server:

```
spring.profiles.include=dev,mysql
```

if for example I would like to activate for all microservices dev and mysql.

Now, I've converted *include* to groups. E.G.:

```
spring.profiles.groups.myConf=dev,mysql
```

(tried also with array notation --> spring.profiles.groups.myConf[0]=dev and [1]=mysql)
and adding to every microservices

```
spring.profiles.active=myConf
```

Watching for the config server logs, it deliver the configuration properly. My problem is that I have some Bean annotated with profile E.g.:

```
@Profile('h2')
```

or

```
@Profile('dev')
```

but these beans are not activated and application not start (also, in startup-logs profiles=[myConf])

The only solution that I found is to insert in every microservice application.properties

```
spring.profile.active=dev,mysql
```

but this don't look very comfortable because I've a lot of microservices.

Which is the proper way?

P.s.: I tried also to not touch anything and use simply

```
spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true
```

in all .properties but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After some month, with Spring Boot 2.6.6, and Spring Framework 5.3.18, this bug is solved.